# Word to describe an action that divide groups

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, idioms, popular-refrains

Greeting,

I am looking for a word that I can use to describe a method that divides a single group into similar smaller groups (not opposing groups).
Something like "schismatic", but without the negative connotation coming from the groups being opposing.

EDIT: the context is I am trying to name a mathematical method using a somewhat distinctive adjective. For example: Calling it the "schismatic method".

Thanks,

Comment: *Divide* is fine for your usage.

Comment: If you suggest the context it is easier to help you. Groups of people, things, animals or what?

Comment: The method I am trying to name is a mathematical method, so the groups do not have a specific nature (they can be group of people, animals, electrons or others). 'Divide' is fine, but calling the method a "dividing method" is too generic.

Comment: Sort of 'creating subsets'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"partition"** may be the word you're looking for.

> "he act or process of dividing something into parts." [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/partition)
>
> - "we shall study three kinds of counting problems, associated with the [**partition of a set into subsets**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Mj9gzZMrXDIC&pg=PA126&dq=partition+mathematics&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAGoVChMI6syY9OqAyQIVwxiQCh2opA1u#v=onepage&q=partition%20mathematics&f=false)"
> - "A most ingeneous device to handle a partition is to look at it graphically. If n = nl + /;2+... : nm is a partition of n (where nl ^ nt $: «3 ^ . . . ^ nm ^ 1)" [**Foundations of Discrete Mathematics**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=RM1D3mFw2u0C&pg=PA106&dq=partition++discrete+mathematics&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAmoVChMI1LOW4euAyQIVAR-QCh3zcAJr#v=onepage&q=partition%20%20discrete%20mathematics&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps say that this method *sow discord* ?

**EDIT** : I can't comment OP's post, so here is another proposition : What about "a partitionning method ?"

That is : a method that create a partition.

Comment: "sow discord" sounds negative to me. Also, I was looking for an adjective. Something I can use like "this is a schismatic method".

Comment: You should precise that you're looking for an adjective then. You should also explain what you mean by "negative". If you have discord in a group, the persons in this group are not necessarily in complete opposition.

Comment: "Partitioning method" sounds great. Thanks. I will use it if I cannot find anything better.